# How to get counts of CSV values in SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, csv, count

I have a table that contains CSV strings for some of the values.

I'd like to get a count of each time an entry in the CSV exists.

However, the count is comparing strings instead of substrings.

**Sample Data**

```
| Category | Items                           |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| Basket 1 | Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Plums |
| Basket 2 | Oranges                         |
| Basket 3 | Oranges, Plums                  |
| Basket 4 | Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Plums |
```

**Sample Select**

```
select distinct 
[key] = 'Items',
[value] = [items],
[count] = count([items])
from someTable
group by [items]
```

**Current Output**

```
| key      | value                           | count |
|----------|---------------------------------|-------|
| Items    | Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Plums | 2     |
| Items    | Oranges                         | 1     |
| Items    | Oranges, Plums                  | 1     |
```

**Expected Output**

```
| key   | value   | count | 
|-------|---------|-------|
| Items | Apples  | 2     | 
| Items | Bananas | 2     | 
| Items | Oranges | 4     | 
| Items | Plums   | 3     |
```

How can I get the count for each CSV entry in a column?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Version 2017...

Comment: Why not fix your design and not store delimited values in your table?

Comment: @Larnu I work with an opinionated DBA...

Comment: An opinated DBA that beleives that poor database design, without being able to implement foreign key constraints, in a denormalised form is a good idea? If that *really* is true, @Matthew , it's time for a new DBA; they shouldn't be working with RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu DId I mention he's also my boss? :)

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it's time to look for a new dba, @Matthew :) Someone being your boss doesn't make them right, and a *good* boss knows when to accept they are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table-valued function to turn the comma-separated values into rows and then count them. You have to remove the spaces because STRING_SPLIT only accepts a singular separator character.

```
create table data
(
  Category varchar(25)
, Items varchar(100)
)

insert into data
values
  ('Basket 1' ,'Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Plums')
, ('Basket 2', 'Oranges')
, ('Basket 3', 'Oranges, Plums')
, ('Basket 4', 'Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Plums')

select 
  'Items' as [key]
 , value
 , count(*) as [count]
from data
cross apply string_split(replace(Items, ' ', ''), ',')
group by value
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f48da5603616c76f9efb6f62b7a3359).

Comment: Could you explain what's going on with `value`? I don't fully understand how it's getting set.

Comment: `Value` is what is returned by STRING_SPLIT.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!